# Changes made in struts.xml don't show in browser. How to refresh?

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, struts2

I'm developing an application that makes use of the struts2 framework, java and webcontent. I use Eclipse as my IDE and tomcat 7.0 as a server. Everything works fine, but when I make changes to the struts.xml file those changes aren't always reflected in my browser.

Here's my workflow:

```
1) Develop/make changes
2) save all
3) start tomcat 7.0 server
4) go to google chrome
5) go to localhost:8080/myWebapplication
6) test the application
```

What bothers me is that sometimes this works and new or changed actions are correctly displayed, while sometimes my application uses the previous sturts.xml and obviously my tests will fail. Why does my browser show this erratic behaviour? Do cookies, the browser cache or refreshing have anything to do with this? To be clear, I restart tomcat (after cleaning) and I restart my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the browser is not enough to clear the cache.

This is a known Chrome issue, I suggest you to turn cache off while developing.

Read more on [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development).